# LVM image still full after removing 6G of files

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

I am runnning ubuntu 14.04 LTS with LVM-images. After a large dataimport into solr I am facing the situation of a full partition of root.

```
 /dev/mapper/vg0-root            9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
```

I found, that the solr log in /var/solr/logs/ contained over 6G and I removed all of them.

Somehow the disc is still full, no change for this partition. What could be causing this and how could I approach this problem to find a solution?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you restart your solr instance after removing the log ?
If your removed the log that the instance is running, then it could be that the file is still written to (and takes the space on the disk) even if you removed it. I had this case once with a process.

Comment: You are right! Solved it :-) Please add this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Just added the answer !  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove a file that a process is writing to, you have to restart the process so it's releasing it for real, otherwise you see it as it's gone but it's still taking space on the filesystem.
So I would advise you to restart the Solr instance.